# How pthread_mutex_unlock distinguish threads?

Tags: c++, c, linux, posix, mutex

Only the owner of mutex can unlock it. But how mutex distinguish thread that locked it?
Does threads have any distinctive features in Linux?

Comment: about multithreading in C, C11 adds `threads.h` in it, so basically now C supports fairly high level abstraction of threading more than before.

Comment: N.B. it is the programmer's responsibility to ensure only the owner unlocks a mutex, in general the mutex is not required to verify that the correct thread unlocks it. (In glibc the thread ID of the owner is stored in the mutex, which is useful for debugging, but that's not required by POSIX).

Comment: @JonathanWakely: It is required for recursive and error-checking mutex types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at the implementation source code for details (the `pthread` implementation from the GNU `libc` Git repository can be browsed [here](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree;f=nptl;h=00d37132d407fc1ffdda6534f93a51bb9c27b560;hb=HEAD)), but they have different IDs that are used internally. You can see this at the application level using `pthread_self()`. It returns a `pthread_t` value that is unique on a per-thread basis within a given process. There is no guarantee of uniqueness when you compare `pthread_t` values from different processes.

The actual type that `pthread_t` corresponds to is implementation-defined, however; it could be an arithmetic (e.g. integral) type, or it could be a structure. Therefore, you can't really do much with them in a portable way, other than compare them for equality using `pthread_equal()`.

Answer (score 2):

They are differentiated using the thread id;